# How to implement a System.Reactive scheduler for ios

Tags: xamarin.ios, system.reactive

I'm using System.Reactive within my ios project and i'm aware i need to use ObserveOn in order to specify on which thread to execute the subscriber on. However i can't seem to get this working properly.

For all i can tell this should be working, or am i implementing it wrong?

```
public class UiContext : IScheduler
{
    /// <inheritdoc />
    public IDisposable Schedule<TState>(TState state, Func<IScheduler, TState, IDisposable> action)
    {
        NSOperationQueue.MainQueue.AddOperation(() => action(this, state));
        return Disposable.Empty;
    }

    /// <inheritdoc />
    public IDisposable Schedule<TState>(TState state, TimeSpan dueTime, Func<IScheduler, TState, IDisposable> action)
    {
        NSOperationQueue.MainQueue.AddOperation(() => action(this, state));
        return Disposable.Empty;
    }

    /// <inheritdoc />
    public IDisposable Schedule<TState>(TState state, DateTimeOffset dueTime, Func<IScheduler, TState, IDisposable> action)
    {
        NSOperationQueue.MainQueue.AddOperation(() => action(this, state));
        return Disposable.Empty;
    }

    /// <inheritdoc />
    public DateTimeOffset Now { get; }
}

    void SomeMethod()
    {
        WhenValidationChanged
            .ObserveOn(new UiContext())
            .SubscribeOn(new UiContext())
            .Throttle(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(50))
            .Subscribe(OnValidationChanged);
    }

    private void OnValidationChanged(object obj)
    {
        if (TableView.DataSource is InfoFieldsDataSource dataSource)
        {
            var validationErrors = dataSource.Items.OfType<InfoFieldViewModelBase>().Count(d => !d.IsValid);
            // Exception is raised about not being executed on UI thread
            _validationController.View.BackgroundColor = validationErrors > 0 ? UIColor.Green : UIColor.Red;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Calling `.ObserveOn(new UiContext())` before `.Throttle(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(50))` probably has no effect as `Throttle` can change the scheduler - each operator can change the scheduler. You should always do `.ObserveOn` just before the operator or subscribe call you want it applied to.

Comment: i will confirm your suggestion monday and let you know if it worked. Thanks in advance

Comment: @Enigmativity make your comment an answer please so i can flag it as correct answer. The order of calling actually did cause this issue. I always thought this is sort of a builder pattern and call order is irrelevant. Thanks!

Comment: It's not building a single object, it's building a pipeline. Order is important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `.ObserveOn(new UiContext())` before `.Throttle(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(50))` probably has no effect as `Throttle` can change the scheduler - each operator can change the scheduler. You should always do `.ObserveOn` just before the operator or subscribe call you want it applied to.